# Node 16: is the --experimental-json-modules CLI flag still required?

Tags: node.js

I have been using the [`--experimental-json-modules`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_json_modules) flag for a while now, to allow me to import JSON, like so:

```
import data from './data.json' assert { type: 'json' };
```

I've recently tried leaving the `--experimental-json-modules` flag out of the command that runs the node app, and I'm not getting any complaints (and it still seems to work OK).

I'm using the latest recommended node version `16.17.0`.

So is this flag required any more, or not?  The only mention of it in the [release notes for node 16](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V16.md) is the [entry for `16.14.0`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V16.md#2022-02-08-version-16140-gallium-lts-danielleadams):

> To keep Node.js ESM implementation as compatible as possible with the HTML spec, import assertions are now required to import JSON modules (still behind the `--experimental-json-modules` CLI flag)

So there was some change, but my reading of the above is that the `--experimental-json-modules` CLI flag is still required?  Except that it doesn't seem to be?

Comment: [Import assertions](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-assertions): _"Added in: v17.1.0, **v16.14.0**"_

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes there is a mention of import assertions in the changelog entry for `16.14.0` that I linked (and even quoted) in my question... but it still suggests that the `--experimental-json-modules` flag is needed. But my question wasn't about import assertions, it was about the need (or otherwise) for the `--experimental-json-modules` flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This merge request](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/41736), which as been merged, mentions:

> This PR unflags JSON modules, removing the `--experimental-json-modules` flag.

In [the changelog](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/198affc63973805ce5102d246f6b7822be57f5fc/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V16.md?plain=1#L1590) for 16.15.0 you can find this in the section "other notable changes":

> (SEMVER-MINOR) unflag esm json modules (Geoffrey Booth)

Comment: Thanks... no big fanfare to go with this change... looks like it's safe to leave it out now.  Though even without the flag there is still a warning when starting the node app: `(node:96096) ExperimentalWarning: Importing JSON modules is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time`.

Comment: Warning still exists as of Node.js v18.15.0

Comment: Warning still exists as of node --version=v21.6.1